# Two rows or two columns with the same number of plusses

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

I have tried drawn numerous tables in attempt to explain this and understand that the number of cells must be even however, I am not sure how to create this proof. I appreciate your support.

Each cell of a square table is filled out either with a plus or minus. It is known that the total number of pluses is equal to the total number of minuses. Prove that there are either two rows or two columns of the table that contain the same number of pluses.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for the $n\times n$ grid, $n$ must be even, in order to satisfy the condition of an equal number of pluses and minuses

In order for all the rows to have different numbers of pluses, we'd need to have rows having $n$ of $0,1,\dots,n$ pluses.  But the $n$ numbers we choose from $0,1,\dots, n$ have to add up to $\frac{n^2}{2}$ (since half the grid has pluses).

Using the well-known formula $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, we see that the unused possible number of pluses must be $\frac{n}{2}$.

In particular there must be a row with $0$ pluses and a row with $n$ pluses.

A similar argument will hold for columns.

Now consider that a row of $0$ pluses is incompatible with a column of $n$ pluses.

Comment: What is n in your answer?

Comment: $n$ is the number of cells in each row (and each column).

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd paragraph you wrote. Please explain.

Comment: Why are we using the formula?

Comment: We are choosing $n$ different numbers from $0, 1, 2, \dots, n$ (since we are choosing a different number of pluses for each row).  We need our $n$ numbers to add up to $\frac{n^2}{2}$ (so that the grid has a total of $\frac{n^2}{2}$ pluses in it).  If we add up all $n+1$ numbers, we have $0+1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}$.  So we want to choose the numbers of pluses in various rows to exclude the number $\frac{n}{2}$ pluses, since that will give us the correct total number of pluses in the grid.